# cocoa tooltip delay per object?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nstableview

According to [this article](http://www.componentix.com/blog/20/change-tooltip-display-delay-in-cocoa-application), you can change the tooltip display for your applications by modifying the `NSInitialToolTipDelay` user default.

So far, this seems to be the only way I have found to modify how long it takes to display a tooltip, however it seems to be application wide.

Does anyone know of a way that I can modify the tooltip speed for one specific `NSTableView`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a minimum of investigation my best (untested) suggestion would be to use mouse tracking regions (mouseEntered: / mouseExited:) along with `[[objc_lookUpClass("NSToolTipManager") sharedToolTipManager] setInitialToolTipDelay:0.1];` (as suggested here: http://lists.apple.com/archives/cocoa-dev/2003/Jan/msg01219.html) to (re)set the delay when the mouse enters/exits the NSTableView's rectangle.